# Class that adds all properties to another object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

For meteor I want to create a class that can easily add all created properties to another object.

Normally one would do the following to add properties to a template:

```
Template.templateName.propertyName = { property: value }
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
class TemplateName extends View

  propertyName:

    property: value
```

What I need to know is how to construct the `View` class above to do this.

**EDIT 1:**

The `View` class should add all properties of it's inheritor to the same-named property of the `Template` class.

So, if `PostsIndex` extends `View` and the property `posts` is added to `PostsIndex`, then this `posts` property with it's value should be added to `Template.PostsIndex`.

**EDIT 2:**

Other options are also welcome, like the following for example:

```
Template.TemplateName.extendWith ->

    propertyName:

        property: value
```

I did not try anything yet, since I have no clue if it's possible or where I need to start.

Is it possible, in a cross-browser way?

Comment: What should the `View` class do? What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: When should this "adding the property" happen? When `TemplateName` is declared? When it's instantiated? Whenever `posts` is changed?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the `TemplateName` programmatically in a safely cross-browser way. Would need some magic with [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) and [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)

Comment: Thanks Bergi, you're probably right, I guess minimization is also going to be a problem..

Comment: @Bergi, the property should be added when the `TemplateName` class is declared.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, there is no hook for that. You'd need to manually call a function (in or around the declaration) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out coffeescript can just do it like this:

```
Template.TemplateName extends

  property: value
```

Comment: No. You're abusing `extends` here, and it will have odd results when not called on a constructor function. Try to replace it by a simple `=` assignment!

Comment: @Bergi That's too bad.. I can't use an `=` assignment because there's already data in this object.. In the following link you'll see how the object `Temlate.TemplateName` is initially created. Isn't this a constructor? Logging shows: `constr {...}`. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/templating/global_template_object.js

Comment: What about assigning to something like `Template.TemplateName.data`? If you don't want that, you'll need some kind of [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function if you use an object literal for the `property`.

Comment: @Bergi The object is part of the meteor framework, so specifying my own property isn't going to work. My main goal is to make it a readable  oneliner followed by the properties the framework needs. `_.extend Template.TemplateName, ` would work, but it looks a bit strange though.

Comment: @Bergi FYI, this is the only function I will extend, if it's no harm to use `extends` here I would definitely use it. In other cases I'd just use `_.extend()`.. Not sure if `Template.TemplateName` is a constructor though and/or what the drawbacks are.

Comment: But the object literal `property: value` is not a constructor. It will actually overwerite/set the `Template.TemplateName.prototype`, which you definitely will not want. Compile it and read the js for what it does.

Comment: Yikes, you're totally right! I don't want that.. I'll just use underscore's extend.. Thanks for the clearance!